# Getting 404 Not Found error when sending a POST request, and 200 OK, when sending GET request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I'm developing a simple registration page using React.js for the frontend and Node.js with Express for the backend. I'm using a PostgreSQL database for data storage. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to send a POST request to the /register/users endpoint from my React.js application, while GET requests to the same endpoint work fine.

This is my register.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Router, Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const userRegex = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{3,23}$/;
const passRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%]).{8,24}$/;

const Register = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [username, setUser] = useState('');
  const [validUsername, setValidUser] = useState(false);

  const [password, setPass] = useState('');
  const [validPassword, setValidPass] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidPass(passRegex.test(password));
  }, [password]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidUser(userRegex.test(username));
  }, [username]);
 
  const isFormValid = validPassword && validUsername; 
  const handleRegister = async () => {
    if (isFormValid) {
      const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10)
      const userData = { username: username, password: hash };
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/register/users', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(userData),
        });
        if (response.ok) {
        // Handle success
        console.log('User registered successfully');
        setTimeout(() => {
            navigate('/login');
          },1500);

        } else {
            // Handle error
            console.log('Error occurred during registration');
        }
      }

      
      catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    } 
    else {
      alert('Please enter valid fields.');
    }
  };
    return <div className="container">
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <form>
          <label htmlFor="username">
            <span className={validUsername ? "valid" : "hide"}></span>
            <span className={validUsername || !username ? "hide" : "invalid"}></span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            id="username"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
            required
            aria-invalid={!validUsername}
          />

          <label htmlFor="password">
            <span className={validPassword ? "valid" : "hide"}></span>
            <span className={validPassword || !password ? "hide" : "invalid"}></span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)}
            required
            aria-invalid={!validPassword}
          />

          <Link to='/login'>
            <button type="submit" onClick = {handleRegister} disabled={!isFormValid}>Register</button>
            <p>Already have an account?</p>
          </Link>   
        </form>
      </div>  
    
};

export default Register;
```

And here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Create a Sequelize instance and connect to your PostgreSQL database
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://pole_chudes:qwerty@localhost:5432/game');

// Import the existing User model
const User = require('./models/users')(sequelize, DataTypes);


sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  });

(async () => {
  await sequelize.sync();
  console.log('Database connected and tables synced');
})();

app.use(express.json());

// Define the registration endpoint
app.post('/register/users', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Create a new user record in the database
    const newUser = await User.create({
      username,
      password,
      score:0
    });

    // Respond with a success message
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during registration
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred during registration' });
  }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I tested the 'https://localhost:3000/register/users' endpoint checking post request using  Postman and received 404 not found.

Comment: Your register.js calls `http://localhost:3000` and you wrote, that you tried `https://localhost:3000` in Postman. That might be, why the Postman gave you that error?

Comment: Thank you,@Geshode, for the review, I did it by mistake, however, when I change it in Postman, still gives me 404 not found.

Comment: fetch('register/users') i think so it fix it

Comment: @NaveenNizam I have tried so, it didn't help though.